# Tomcat Settings for Moyocore.dll

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm struggling with `moyocore_x64.dll` on Tomcat:

1. In which folder do i have to put this dll?
2. in which folder do i have to put the jar-file: `moyocore.jar`?
3. is there additional settings in other (Tomcat)-files to be done?